# Elasticsearch 2.2 : Cannot parse dates

Tags: date, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have ES 2.2.0 and i am trying to parse dates like this

```
2012-07-09 03:12:12.553
```

Here is my mapping definition

```
"DocDate":
{
    "type": "date",
    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
}
```

but I get

```
raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'mapper_parsing_exception', u'failed to parse [DocDate]')
```

am I using an incorrect format? Is there a way for ES to auto convert to the format specified in the mapping?

Comment: It is working for me on ES 1.7. ES 2.2 was released yesterday only, could be a bug, not 100% sure. Did you find anything useful in ES logs?

Comment: not really. i guess i can try to convert my date to a simpler format and then see if it works

Comment: It also works on ES 2.0, `PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "doctype": {
      "properties": {
        "docdate": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`
I insert document like this, it works
`PUT test/doctype/1
{
  "docdate" : "2012-07-09 03:12:12.553"
}`

Comment: oh you are right, in fact there was some data that was incorrect. i had stuff like 2012-02-21 14:14:24.617000